# Prove $A=\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq f(x)\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):0<y<f(x)\}$ , $B$, are measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ measurable Lebesgue and let $l_2$ the measure of Lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove the set:

$$A=\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq f(x)\}$$ and $$B=\{(x,y):0<y<f(x)\}$$

are measurable lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and

$$l_2\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq f(x)\}=l_2\{(x,y):0<y<f(x)\}=\int f(x)$$

**My attempt:**

Note:
$$A=\{(x,y): y\geq 0\}\cap \{(x,y): f(x)\geq y\}= X \times \{y\geq 0\}\cap \{(x,y):f(x)-y\geq 0\}$$

The first intersection  $X \times \{y\geq 0\}$ is a rectangle then, is measurable.

Now, for $\{(x,y):f(x)-y\geq 0\}$ we have:

$(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)) \ni (x,y) \mapsto f(x) \in (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable because $f$ is measurable.

$(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)) \ni (x,y) \mapsto y \in (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable because this function is continuous.

then:

$(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)) \ni (x,y) \mapsto g(y,x) := f(x) -y\in (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable.

As the finite intersection of measurable set is measurable then $A$ is measurable.

Analogous with $B$

I'm stuck here:

$$l_2\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq f(x)\}=l_2\{(x,y):0<y<f(x)\}=\int f(x)$$

Comment: Recall that the preimage of a measurable set under a measurable map is measurable, and that the countable (hence finite) intersection of measurable set is measurable.

Comment: Edited, thanks @Javi

Comment: How is your integral defined in your context? In some textbook (such as Wheeden & Zygmund), the integral of non-negative functions are actually defined as the measure of the region under the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the composition $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),y)\mapsto y-f(x).$

Or do it from scratch: First, restrict the domain of $f$ to $[-m,m]$. Now find simple functions $g_n,h_n$ such that $g_n\le f\le h_n$ and $h_n-g_n\le 1/n.$Then, $A(g_n)\le A\le A(h_n).$ Then, it's easy to see that $m(\cup A(g_n))=m(A)$ so $A$ is a union of a null set and $\cup A(g_n)$ and so is measurable. (You can use $\cap A(h_n)$ also. The argument is the same). The general case will follow by taking the union over $m$ of the sets we just found.